# Difference between select and collect

Tags: ruby

Can't understand the difference between `select` and `collect` methods. Also want to know when to use each.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Enumerable#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) (or [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)) returns a result of applying block to each items.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].collect { |x| x > 2 }
# => [false, false, true, true]
```

While [`Enumerable#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) returns an array of filtered items:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].select { |x| x > 2 }
# => [3, 4]
```

Comment: `collect` is also known as `map` and in other languages `select` known as `filter`. I see `map` used more than `collect` in code I read.